# JavaScript error in IE7 & IE8: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get the value of property 'newQuestion': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I've been looking all over and can't come up with a solution. The following code works perfectly in IE9, Chrome, FF, and Safari. However, when you hit "Start" in IE7 or IE8 you get the following error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get the value of property 'newQuestion': object is null or undefined
```

The code at issue is here:

```
//This is used to reduce some code size and not type document.getElementById(a) each time
function DOMelem(a) {
    return document.getElementById(a);
}
//This is used to round numbers
function roundTo(a,b) {
    a=a*Math.pow(10,b);
    a=Math.round(a);
    a=a/Math.pow(10,b);
    return a;
}
//The quiz object
function sQuiz(a,c,init) {
    //This part is used to get the variable used by the user
    this.getName=function() {
        for(var v in window) {
            if(window[v] instanceof sQuiz) {
                this.varName=v;
            }
        }   
    },
    //This will create the first page of the quiz
    this.createQuiz=function() {
        this.getName();
        DOMelem(a).innerHTML="<h1>"+init.intro.qTitle+"</h1>";
        DOMelem(a).innerHTML+="<h2>"+init.intro.qAuthor+"</h2>";
        DOMelem(a).innerHTML+="<h3>"+init.intro.qComments+"</h3><br /><br />";
        DOMelem(a).innerHTML+="<input type='button' value='Start' onClick='"+this.varName+".newQuestion(0)'>";
    },
    //This one will create a random id for the quiz and create a bar for it
    this.createBar=function() {
        id="12391023103091"+Math.round(Math.random()*12391023103091);
        id=id.substr(id.length-14,14);
        this.randBarId=id;
        DOMelem(c).innerHTML="<div class='progress_full' id='pro_"+id+"'><div class='progress_bar' style='width:0%;' id='bar_"+id+"'></div></div>";
    },
    //In this section we check to see if there's a bar, if we must show the results or just show the interface.
    this.newQuestion=function(index) {
        //Create the bar if it does not exist
        if(!DOMelem("pro_"+this.randBarId)||!DOMelem("bar_"+this.randBarId)) {
            eval(this.varName+".createBar()");
        }
        //Show the results page
        if(index>=init.questions.length) {
            eval(this.varName+".showResults()");
        }
        //Show the question interface
        else {
            DOMelem(a).innerHTML="<h1>"+init.questions[index].question+"</h1>";
            for (var i=0;i<init.questions[index].answers.length;i++) {
                DOMelem(a).innerHTML+="<input type='button' name='"+index+"_"+i+"' value='"+init.questions[index].answers[i]+"' onClick='"+this.varName+".checkAnswer("+index+","+i+")'>";
            }
            DOMelem(a).innerHTML+="<input type='submit' id='btn_"+this.randBarId+"' value='Next Question' onClick='"+this.varName+".changeQuestion("+index+")' disabled>";
            DOMelem("bar_"+this.randBarId).style.width=(((index+1)/init.questions.length)*100)+"%";
        }
    },
    //This is used when the user clicks to change the question 
    this.changeQuestion=function(index) {
        return this.newQuestion(index+1);
    },
    //This part handles when the user clicks on an answer, color it, un-disable the button and record the guess
    this.checkAnswer=function(index,i) {
        init.questions[index].guessed=i;
        var inputs=document.getElementById(a).getElementsByTagName("input");
        for(var j=0;j<inputs.length;j++) {
            document.getElementById(a).getElementsByTagName("input")[j].className="";
            if(inputs[i].name==index+"_"+i) {
                document.getElementById(a).getElementsByTagName("input")[i].className="selected";
            }
        }
        DOMelem("btn_"+this.randBarId).disabled=false;
    },
    //This one here shows the result of the quiz.
    this.showResults=function() {
        DOMelem(a).innerHTML="<h1>Results of "+init.intro.qTitle+"</h1>";
        var count=0;
        for(var i=0;i<init.questions.length;i++) {
            if(init.questions[i].guessed==(init.questions[i].correctAnswer-1)) {
                count++;
                DOMelem(a).innerHTML+="<div id='answer' class='correct'>&radic; Question "+(i+1)+"</div>";
            }
            else {
                DOMelem(a).innerHTML+="<div id='answer' class='wrong'>&times; Question "+(i+1)+"</div>";
            }
        }
        var result=roundTo((count/init.questions.length)*100,2);
        DOMelem(a).innerHTML+="<h3 style='clear:both'><br />"+result+"% correct answers.</h3>";
        var tweet=init.tweetText.replace(/--score--/gi,result+"%");
        tweet=tweet.replace(/ /gi,'+');
        tweet="https://www.twitter.com/share?text="+tweet;
        DOMelem(a).innerHTML+="<a href='"+tweet+"'>Tweet it</a>";
    }   
}
```

You can view a demo [here](http://ktbaker.com/quiz).

I really think I've read about every related question, but still can't come up with a solution. Please let me know if any additional information would be helpful.

UPDATE:

To clarify, I am testing in IE9 with compatibility mode turned on. If anyone actually has IE7 or IE8 installed, I would live to know your results. Anyway, the code seems to execute up until here:

```
    //This will create the first page of the quiz
    this.createQuiz=function() {
        this.getName();
        DOMelem(a).innerHTML="<h1>"+init.intro.qTitle+"</h1>";
        DOMelem(a).innerHTML+="<h2>"+init.intro.qAuthor+"</h2>";
        DOMelem(a).innerHTML+="<h3>"+init.intro.qComments+"</h3><br /><br />";
        DOMelem(a).innerHTML+="<input type='button' value='Start' onClick='"+this.varName+".newQuestion(0)'>";
    },
```

Once the start button is clicked, I get an error because `this.varName` returns as `undefined`.

Comment: Can you reduce this to the minimum possible that still shows the error?

Comment: Using IE 9 in compatability mode is related to page layout and formatting, I don't think it makes any change to the script engine. Can you post a working snippet that shows the error?

Comment: @RobG Did you try http://ktbaker.com/quiz ?

Comment: Yes, the page doesn't work at all in IE8.

Answer (score 2):

In your code:

```
> //The quiz object
```

Is really a function object, not a plain object. And do you expect to call it as a constructor? I can't get to the demo.

Likely this:

```
> this.getName=function() {
>     for(var v in window) {
>         if(window[v] instanceof sQuiz) {
>             this.varName=v;
>         }
>     }
> },
```

<strike>is treated as a syntax error because it is terminated with a comma instead of a semi–colon</strike>. No, it's not.

#### Edit

Your problem is here:

```
    for(var v in window) {
         if(window[v] instanceof sQuiz) {
             this.varName=v;
         }
    }
```

Global variables are not enumerable in IE 8 (and probably earlier), so you never find the instance(s) of sQuiz you are looking for and *this.varName* remains undefined (actually, the object will not have a *varName* property at all, unless you add it some other way elsewhere).

You need to use some other method of referencing the instance(s)— perhaps using the module pattern and keeping a reference in a closure, or an array of references to each instance.

Comment: @ARP is (likely inadvertently) using the comma operator to separate those function expressions. The comma operator evaluates each expression, in order, and returns the value of the final expression in the chain. I don't have IE7 and 8 handy to test, but it's not unreasonable to guess that this relatively obscure operator might be (at least) one of the problems in these older browsers.

Comment: I removed the commas and also tried replacing them with semicolons. Unfortunately, I got the same result. Is the demo still unavailable for you?

Comment: @KenRedler—yes, aware that comma is syntacically OK, just took a guess - and was wrong. No surprises there.

Comment: @RobG, Yup, figured you knew. Just adding some detail since the comma as an operator, rather than separator, is kind of rare. I guess it doesn't solve the poster's problem, but it makes for some [interesting reading](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I get a JavaScript error when I load the page in IE. This line:-

```
if(window[v] instanceof sQuiz)
```

is failing - you should check window[v] for null first before instanceof