# Underscore.js template throwing error in ie8 in _.each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, templates, underscore.js

I'm using underscore.js to render JSON data http://pastebin.com/WrUfT1Z4 into a template. It works fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE9 + 10, but throws an error in ie8.

> "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'slug' of undefined or null
>   reference  Function code (2), line 6 character 1"

In the IE8 debugger, the following is highlighted:

```
 _.each(things,function(thing,key,list){ 
__p+='\n\t\t\t        \n\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class="accordion-heading">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a class="no-ajaxy accordion-toggle ic-minus block collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#things-'+
((__t=( thing.slug ))==null?'':__t)+
'">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'+
((__t=( thing.title ))==null?'':__t)+
'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</div> <!-- header -->\n\t\t\t            \n\t\t\t\t\t\t<div id="things-'+
((__t=( thing.slug ))==null?'':__t)+
'" class="accordion-body collapse">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class="accordion-inner">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t';
```

Does anyone have any idea what can be causing this error and if anything can be done to resolve it? There is a similar question here but I'm not sure how the answer applies to my code (original code below). [JavaScript error in IE7 & IE8: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get the value of property 'newQuestion': object is null or undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889841/javascript-error-in-ie7-ie8-script5007-unable-to-get-the-value-of-property/8889970#8889970)

Thanks!

Here is the original underscore template that's causing the error:

```
<script type="text/x-underscore" id='furniture-template'>
    <div class="accordion collapse">
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <% _.each(things,function(thing,key,list){ %>

            <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="no-ajaxy accordion-toggle ic-minus block collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#things-<%= thing.slug %>">
                    <%= thing.title %>
                </a>
            </div> <!-- header -->

            <div id="things-<%= thing.slug %>" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <% for(var item in thing.items) { %>
                    <div class="item">
                        <% if( thing.items[item].images == true ) { %>
                            <a class="no-ajaxy" data-target="<%= thing.items[item].slug %>-gal" class="img-link ic-cam fl" title="View an example"></a>
                        <% } %>

                        <a 
                            class="item-add ic-plus" 
                            data-title="<%= thing.items[item].title %>" 
                            data-slug="<%= thing.items[item].slug %>"
                            data-img="<%= thing.items[item].images %>"
                            data-shorthand="<%= thing.items[item].shorthand %>"
                            data-price="<%= thing.items[item].price %>"
                        >
                            <%= thing.items[item].title %>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <% } %>
                </div> <!-- inner -->
            </div> <!-- accordion-body -->

        <% }); %>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var template = $("#furniture-template").html();
        $furnitureList = _.template(template, {things: things});
});
```

Comment: That odd looking function is the compiled form of your template. Have you looked at `things` and `thing`?

Comment: Here's the JSON array. http://pastebin.com/WrUfT1Z4

Comment: You have a problem on line 177, older IEs don't like trailing commas, it turns them into `null` entries in your array.

Comment: That is the answer. Thanks so much, I was pulling my hair hout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue as mu is too short pointed out was that there was a trailing comma at the end of my JSON array which was causing the error. Removing the comma resolved the problem.

Comment: I can't believe that THIS was my issue... but, thanks for adding this answer.